# Laravel Backend not getting files from form

Tags: laravel

I am trying to upload multiple files, and in the process there should be a temporary storage which is later on deleted.

In my blade file, I have the following:

```
<form action="/logo/post" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
<input type="file"
class="filepond"
name="files[]"
id="files"
multiple
data-allow-reorder="true"
data-max-file-size="3MB"
data-max-files="3">
</form>
```

So, in name, I have `files[]` and on my id I have `files`.

In my `UploadController` where I am handling the temporary upload I am making use of the following function:

```
public function store(Request $request){
        $input = $request->all();
        $files=array();
        if($filesUp=$request->file('files')){
            foreach($filesUp as $file){
                $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $folder = uniqid() . '-' . now()->timestamp;
                $file->storeAs('/files/tmp/' . $folder, $name);
                $files[]=$name;

                TemporaryFile::create([
                    'folder' => $folder,
                    'filename' => $name
                ]);

            }

            return $folder;
        }

        return '';
    }
```

So, everything goes fine by now, but the issue appears when I try to make use of this in the other controller. The other controller is NOT getting the files, I tried `dd` to check if it's getting any files, and it says `null`.

This is the code in the other controller:

```
public function store(Request $request){

        $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'color' => 'required|string|max:7',
            'description' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'price' => 'required|numeric|between:0,99999.99',
        ]);

        $logo = new Logo([
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'category_id' => 1,
            'title' => $request->title,
            'color' => $request->color,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'price' => $request->price,
        ]);

        $logo->save();

        $files=array();
        if($filesUp=$request->file('files')){
            foreach($filesUp as $file){
                $temporaryFile = TemporaryFile::where('folder', $file)->first();
                if($temporaryFile){
                    $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                    $folder = uniqid() . '-' . now()->timestamp;
                    $file->storeAs('/files/' . $folder, $name);
                    $files[]=$name;
                    rmdir(storage_path('app/public/files/tmp/' . $file));
                    $temporaryFile->delete();
                    File::create([
                        'logo_id' => $logo->id,
                        'name' => $name
                    ]);
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Why is the other controller not getting any files?

Comment: did you add multipart in your form

Comment: Do your form include `enctype='multipart/form-data'`?

Comment: Yes, still NULL

Answer (score 0):

Upload controller and other controller is accessed in which way? From form it is first going to upload controller and returning to form then going to other controller? If so check if image upload field getting empty after returning from upload controller to the form to submit to the other controller. Better you show your form also.

Answer (score 0):

You can bring the files back to the form when returning to form after temporary save controller, and submit to original one

Answer (score 0):

**CHECK!!!** your config on php.ini

may be, like me, is desactivated.